# jQuery UI buttons and anchor tags

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

If you look at the buttons demo page, you'll see that the anchor tag is slightly different in size than the other two (at least in chrome). This is due to the default styles applied by the browser.

See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/

Is there any quick and easy fix to make 'anchor buttons' look exactly like normal buttons?

Comment: As a reference, here is an open jQuery ticket documenting this issue: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5254

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you modify or override (recommended) the vertical padding on line 18 of jquery.ui.button.css you should be able to fix it.
Here's the current block:

```
.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text {
    padding: 0.4em 1em;
}
```

Here's a potential fix:

```
.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text {
    padding: 0.3em 1em;
}
```

Only tested it in the Webkit nightly so you'll want to run it through other browsers to verify.